# bqplot: ipython widgets not being rendered

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets, bqplot

I am trying to use [**bqplot**](https://github.com/bloomberg/bqplot) to plot some graphs in jupyter notebook along with some ipywidgets. I want to render the widgets horizontally adjacent to my plot as discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/ipython/ipywidgets/issues/1067), but I cannot get the widgets to show up in my jupyter notebook.

My code is as follows -

```
from bqplot import pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as widgets
from pandas import DataFrame

class AdderDOEProblem_PlotUtils:
    def __init__(self, parseutils):
        self.data = DataFrame({'timestamps': parseutils.getTimestampValues(),
                            'Adder.sum': parseutils.getValues('Adder.sum'),
                            'Adder.a': parseutils.getValues('desvar_a.a'),
                            'Adder.b': parseutils.getValues('desvar_b.b')})
        # step size
        self.Adder_a__step = 0.1
        self.Adder_b__step = 0.1

        # axes configuration
        x_axis_values = self.data['Adder.a']
        y_axis_values = self.data['Adder.sum']

        self.fig = plt.figure(title='AdderDOEProblem')
        self.p = plt.plot(x_axis_values, y_axis_values)

        w_a_slider = widgets.FloatSlider(value=0, min=0, max=1, step=self.Adder_a__step, description='Adder.a')
        w_b_slider = widgets.FloatSlider(value=0, min=0, max=1, step=self.Adder_b__step, description='Adder.b')
        self.widgets_list = [w_a_slider, w_b_slider]

    def update (self, change):
        # Placeholder logic for testing 
        self.p.y = [i+1 for i in self.p.y]

    def plot (self):
        plt.show()
        for w in self.widgets_list:
            w.observe(self.update, 'value')
        self.update(None)
        widgets.HBox([widgets.VBox(self.widgets_list), self.fig])
```

When I run it in the notebook, I get the following output -

[image: jupyter notebook output]

I have tried the following command as suggested in many of the threads (but with no luck) -

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

What am I missing?

P.S. The versions of the packages are as follows -
jupyter - 1.0.0
ipython - 5.1.0
ipywidgets - 5.2.2
bqplot - 0.8.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your plot function, you have to return the `HBox` which is being created. That is why it is not being displayed. The figure which is displayed comes from the `plt.show` command, which only shows the `Figure` in the current context. Notice that you don't need the `plt.show()` anymore. So the plot function would look like,

```
def plot (self):
    for w in self.widgets_list:
        w.observe(self.update, 'value')
    self.update(None)
    return widgets.HBox([widgets.VBox(self.widgets_list), self.fig])
```

Comment: You might need a final display call. ```from IPython.display import display; a = AdderDOEProblem_PlotUtils(); box = a.plot(); display(box)```.

Comment: Also, I imagine that if your sliders are meant to control the ```self.plot```, they will do this adequately through ```update()```. That is, I'm not sure you need ```update()``` within ```plot()```.